# SELECT field records from a table if it doesn't match a record in another two columns table

Tags: multiple-columns, multiple-tables

I really worked on this weird code a lot, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for
I searched on your wonderful website for an answer as usually I find it here, but none found

however, I have two tables that contains let say one column in the first table and two columns in the other.

I want to select all the records in the first table (the one column table) that doesn't match in the second table columns.

If you look here:

### table 1

### username

user1
user2
user3
user4
user5

And

### table 2

### you | friend

('user1', 'user2')
('user2', 'user3')
('user3', 'user1')
('user4', 'user3')

so basically What I want the records that never match 'user1' in table 1 and table 2
also I don't want anything that match 'user1' on the other side of the column and vise-verse

In conclusion, I want the returns of the field username to be as in order
'user4'
'user5'

So now you have the picture I have this link [Live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dd94/13)

so you don't need to worry about write any DB

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated answer following the conversation with OP:-

```
SELECT username
FROM (
  SELECT username FROM users
  UNION
  SELECT you FROM friends
  UNION
  SELECT friend FROM friends
) everybody
WHERE everybody.`username` != 'user1'
```

Substitute the username being test in the final string.

The UNION does a DISTINCT by default, removing any extra results.

====================== original answer from here ======================

I don't understand your question - but this may give you an idea of where to start...

```
SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE username NOT IN (
  SELECT you
  FROM friends
  UNION
  SELECT friend
  FROM friends
  )
```

This is probably more efficient, especially if indexes exist to cover the EXISTS:-

```
SELECT u.username
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM friends f
  WHERE (f.you=u.username OR f.friend=u.username)
  )
```

Comment: can you make it return all the users table fields records?

Comment: the username column is the only one you have defined for the users table

Comment: oh my bad. I got it anyways.
but thanks your code answered my question perfectly :)

Comment: Just added a better approach using exists (no need for the creation of temporary tables - less strain on server - and much quicker, if indexes exist).  Up vote my answer if it has helped...

Comment: no problem.  I see you've marked it as the accepted answer - which was what I meant..  :-)   glad to have helped.

Comment: your second code could return 'user1' from username field 
I put AND 'user1' != u.username and it still return 'user1'
not in a similar db thu

Comment: SELECT u.username FROM users u WHERE '$username' <> u.username AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM friends f WHERE (f.you = u.username OR f.friend = u.username)) that works

Comment: if you run either of my solutions in your sqlfiddle - you get user5 and user6 in the result set.  I don't understand what you are saying - user1 is never returned.

Comment: if you don't have anything in the friends table you will get 'user1'

Comment: If you are reading this, the code didn't work as wanted to be, but accidentally it gave similar results to what i was expecting.
I wanted the yous and the friends that doesn't match 'user1'